# How to fix websockets which are giving a NetworkError: 400 Unsupported draft specification: 13

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, maven-3

I'm trying to use an example from [this website](http://webtide.intalio.com/2011/08/websocket-example-server-client-and-loadtest/) in order to learn how to use web-socket in jetty. I'm using maven to gather dependencies.

When I open the page in localhost:8082, the page appears(it's a chat client), however if I try to login(which is when web-sockets are used first) nothing happens. Using Firebug, I determined that the error messages I get are as follows:

```
"NetworkError: 400 Unsupported draft specification: 13 - http://localhost:8082/chat"
```

and also

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8082/chat
```

I checked the jar(version 7.5.0.RC1) for web sockets and it turns out that the WebSocketFactory does not support Sec-WebSocket-Draft 13.

I updated the jars to the latest version(8.0.3.v20111011), which does support version 13:

```
    switch (draft)
    {
        case -1:
        case 0:
            extensions=Collections.emptyList();
            connection = new WebSocketConnectionD00(websocket, endp, _buffers, http.getTimeStamp(), _maxIdleTime, protocol);
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6: 
            extensions=Collections.emptyList();
            connection = new WebSocketConnectionD06(websocket, endp, _buffers, http.getTimeStamp(), _maxIdleTime, protocol);
            break;
        case 7:
        case 8:
            extensions= initExtensions(extensions_requested,8-WebSocketConnectionD08.OP_EXT_DATA, 16-WebSocketConnectionD08.OP_EXT_CTRL,3);
            connection = new WebSocketConnectionD08(websocket, endp, _buffers, http.getTimeStamp(), _maxIdleTime, protocol,extensions,draft);
            break;
        case 13:
            extensions= initExtensions(extensions_requested,8-WebSocketConnectionD13.OP_EXT_DATA, 16-WebSocketConnectionD13.OP_EXT_CTRL,3);
            connection = new WebSocketConnectionD13(websocket, endp, _buffers, http.getTimeStamp(), _maxIdleTime, protocol,extensions,draft);
            break;
        default:
            LOG.warn("Unsupported Websocket version: "+draft);
            response.setHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Version","0,6,8,13");
            throw new HttpException(400, "Unsupported draft specification: " + draft);
    }
```

...but I still get the same error. On top of that, I now get errors in the code, saying that the constructor WebSocketClient() is deprecated and that a number of methods I was using don't exist in WebSocketClient.

So I guess my questions are:

1) What is causing this to run version 13 and how can I get it to use version 8?
2) Has anybody else tried to use this tutorial and had trouble?
3) Is there an easier way to learn websockets(maybe this example is out of date already)?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For code readability I would define those cases as constants rather than just using the integer values.  Easier for us to read. :)

Comment: Well, I would, except for two things. 1) This is the code from inside a jar file which I can view in eclipse, but can't modify, and 2) I have no idea what I'd name them. I am after all trying to learn how this program works. This was just the relevant section from the file I got from the maven repository, so I don't think I'm really to blame over it's readability.

Comment: The version of websockets being used will be determined by the Sec-Websocket-Version header in the initial handshake from your browser.  Can you use Fiddler and check what this is?

Comment: Note also that Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13 matches the draft standard so you'll want your server to support it.  Is the source code for the server available?

Comment: "I updated the jars to the latest version(8.0.3.v20111011)" the latest version is 8.1.6.v20120716...just saying...